# Is relying on 3 ft. of steel a D&D thing?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, product-identification

Several years ago, a friend who played *Dungeons and Dragons* described the difference between wizards, monsters, and fighters as, "When your spells fail, when your saves fail, you can always rely on 3 feet of steel."

Was he quoting a *Dungeons and Dragons* book?

Comment: Do not answer in comments.

Answer (score 9):

I don't believe this is from a D&D source.  It parallels a quote from Larry Niven's 1980s vintage novel, *The Magic Goes Away*: "Those damned stupid barbarians with their damned stupid swords will win in the end -- because a sword *always* works."  It's likely he'd read this book and misquoted that statement from one of the major characters.

Comment: That seems like a reach, it has the same general sentiment but so do many things.